# How to return paramer from object of array if property name include value?

Tags: javascript

If i have an array :

`[{month:'January', value:1},{month:'February', value:2}]` and so on how can i check if month in array includes for example Jan and then return 1, Feb return 2 and so on?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking for `input.find(x => x.month.includes("Jan"))?.value` ? It would return `undefined` if it cannot find it otherwise it would return the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?
You can create a regular expression and test it.

If your search should be case insensitive, change the RegExp as follows,

`const pattern = new RegExp("^" + month, 'i');`

Note that `^` matches the start of a string without consuming any characters.

```js
const array = [{
  month: 'January',
  value: 1
}, {
  month: 'February',
  value: 2
}];

function findValue(month) {
  const pattern = new RegExp("^" + month);
  const m = array.find(c => pattern.test(c.month));
  return m && m.value || null;
}

console.log(findValue("Jan"))
console.log(findValue("Feb"))
```

Comment: i want to pass value and check if includes in array and then return value, for example i want to pass Jan and check if includes in January return value

Comment: i dont want to pass whole value just first few letters

Comment: tnx :) just one more question...how can i make it that is not important if its uppercase or lowercase when i pass the value

Comment: @None, Please see my answer, it is much simpler and does a case insensitive search, initially I posted that answer in comments of the question but I guess you didn't notice

Comment: @None you can simply use `i` flag :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const monthsArray = [{month:'January', value:1},{month:'February', value:2}];
const month = 'Jan';
console.log(monthsArray.find(m => m.month.includes(month)))
```

(credit to  Hamza Khanzada in the comment).

`Includes` on a String property will check whether the prop has the value you are checking for in it, and will return a match or undefined.

You can leverage that further with a wrapper function as in the other answer

Comment: i dont want to pass whole value just first few letters

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
This essentially does a case-insensitive search.

```js
let monthToFind = 'jan';

let input = [{month:'January', value:1},{month:'February', value:2}];
let result = input.find(x => x.month.toLowerCase().includes(monthToFind.toLowerCase()))?.value;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate that the month starts with

```js
const months = [{
    month: 'January',
    value: 1
}, {
    month: 'February',
    value: 2
}];

function matchMonth(intialsMonth) {
    return months.find(res => res.month.toLowerCase().startsWith(intialsMonth.toLowerCase())).value;
}

console.log(matchMonth("Jan"));
console.log(matchMonth("Feb"));
```